# What is this plant, please help

Tags: plant-recommendations, safety

[image]

What is this plant? It just started showing up in my yard. There are now 5 between me and my neighbors houses. I have a neuro atypical nephew that stays with me and loves to eat leaves so I need to make sure its safe.

Comment: Where do you live? Continent/region.

Answer (score 1):

These are maples. Probably Acer platanoides or Acer rubrum, but I am not sure.

Take a look at this question for identification:

[Acer platanoides vs Acer pseudoplatanus](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35813/acer-platanoides-vs-acer-pseudoplatanus/35818?r=SearchResults#35818)

This guide will tell you something about whether maple leaves are poisonous:

https://homeguides.sfgate.com/varieties-maple-poisonous-63160.html

No matter what, I would advise you to remove them,  just in case.

Comment: It is not a Silver and I doubt it is Red ( rubrum); It does not look like the reds in my yard.

Comment: Looks like Sugar or Black ( possibly a Norway if they have been introduced in your area.) I never heard of anyone allergic to Maple leaves but anything is possible.

Comment: Find the adult trees and maybe you can collect juice and make syrup next winter.

Comment: It doesn't seem Acer platanoides. On the other hand, there are many cultivars, so it is difficult to find it out. And seedlings have often different leaves (the reddish leaves is one of them, common on young leaves).

Comment: If it's an Acer platanoides, when a pluck a leaf from the stem the "sap" will be milky.